# Need help making my logo stand out from the background

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, logo, critique

[image]

I would like to ask for suggestions on how to make the logo (Printzilla House) below stand out more on the pattern background. I've tried adding an oval white shape, but it seems to look a bit weird.

I would appreciate it if you guys could suggest what I could do to make it look better.

Comment: Maybe this is just me being a perfectionist, but the fact that the background pattern is not perfectly centered within the template immediately caught my eye (the pattern needs to be shifted left a tiny bit)

Answer (score 1):

I would try applying outline to it, for example with the color of the outline in logo above. Try different colors - maybe focus on lighter ones.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could also try using this same method but using a big white transparent stripe instead of ovale.

You can also add an outline (a thick one) that would take the very background color.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely add an outline (below the black one to create contrast) with a bright and light color that will maximize the number of occasions when your logo is the main point of view. Then they might even look at its details.

Answer (score 0):

I would place the logo in a white  container having the shape of these on the background (the white ones) and I would definitely change the outline from black to background color. That way you'd achieve both better connection between the logo and your design and a nice, simple stand-out logo.